# Laravel 5 phpunit is not running tests

Tags: php, phpunit, laravel-5

I'm been at this for days with no success. Running `Laravel 5.1`.
As I understand according to the `Laravel` doc.

> An ExampleTest.php file is provided in the tests directory. After installing a new Laravel application, simply run phpunit on the command line to run your tests.

Ok so after running `phpunit` I found it is not globally installed and is located in `vendor/bin/phpunit`. Proceeding to run `vendor/bin/phpunit` gives me a screen with all the command options for phpunit. Its does not actually run any tests.

I searched more and came across a [post](https://laracasts.com/discuss/channels/general-discussion/phpunit-woes) that mentioned it could be a `symlink` issue. I followed the instructions in the [post](https://laracasts.com/discuss/channels/general-discussion/phpunit-woes) with no success. From memory I installed `Laravel` from composer so the `symlink` should not be an issue anyway.

These instructions involved deleting various files. I did notice that composer was pulling files from its cache when updating. So I cleared its cache and followed the process again. Still no success.

What are the tests not running? I'm at my wits end. Especially since its is supposed to run easily out the box.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

In the end I was not calling the bat file correctly. I was running

`C:\localhost\myProject\vendor\bin> phpunit`

Instead I needed to run

`C:\localhost\myproject> call vendor\bin\phpunit`

Hence it now is referencing the `phpunit.xml` file with the test location information.

Answer (score 2):

You need to install phpunit globally:
`composer global require phpunit/phpunit`

Then you can run `phpunit` from your project root.

Comment: Thats not the same thing though. I may want to run different versions of phpunit in different projects

Answer (score 1):

You could just run the phpunit that comes with the project, just go to your project root and run `./vendor/bin/phpunit`, that way the tests will execute the way they should be and you could get feedback in case it fails.

For some reason I haven't figure out yet if you install phpunit globally in your computer you won't get feedback of your tests.